# when i use FacebookClient class in my java Bean the xhtml doesn't run

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I tried  these simple java and xhtml codebut it doesn't  work .

```
@ManagedBean(name = "connecter")
@RequestScoped
@SessionScoped
public class Connecter 
{


    int nombre;

    public Connecter()
    {
```

//here i will enter the access token that i get from Graph API Explorer//

```
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("");
        Connection<User> myFriends = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class, Parameter.with("fields", "id, name,picture"));

        nombre = myFriends.getData().size();

    }

    public int getNombre()
    {

        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(int nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

//Here is my web.xml file including the servlet mapping . So how can I check if the url fall in the Faces Servlet URL??

```
     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>..</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
   <context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    ..</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    ..'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    ..
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't run"? The page gives a 404 error? Exceptions? Blank screen?

Comment: That mean when I run it , a 404 error appears in the web page

Comment: Then you're requesting an invalid URL. What's the URL you're requesting and what's the actual physical path to the page you're requesting? Also look out for exceptions in your console/logs (although this is less likely, code errors will give HTTP 500 errors)

Answer (score 1):

A managed bean can't have several scopes at the same time. Remove `@RequestScoped` or `@SessionScoped` annotation from your managed bean.

Your managed bean logic should not be in your bean constructor, instead use `@PostConstruct` method:

```
public class Connecter {
    int nombre;
    public Connecter() {
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //be sure to have this myFriend object declared and initialized here as well
        //also, manage the Exceptions here...
        //this is a plain basic example
        try {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("");
            Connection<User> myFriends = facebookClient.fetchConnection(
                "me/friends", User.class,
                 Parameter.with("fields", "id, name,picture"));
            //here I will ...
            nombre = myFriends.getData().size();
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            nombre = 0;
         }
    }
    //getters, setters, other methods...
}
```

Comment: @rihab you haven't posted what's your exact problem, so just giving you the basic elements to get the real exception in order to edit your question, post the stacktrace or something that can tell us what problem do you have. Note that we can't just guess what problem is with a code that compiles and run.

Comment: when I run the xhtml using #{connecter.nombre} i get a 404 error , and when I remove the FacebookClient and I run it i get 0 (which is the value of nombre)

Comment: @rihab looks like there was a problem when retrieving info from your FaceBook classes. Note that I've wrapped all this logic inside a try/catch block. This code should at least prevent your page from this error. Also, make sure to rebuild, clean and redeploy your project in order to run this code and not the old one.

Comment: @rihab how are you accessing to your page?

Comment: @rihab seems that you're using NetBeans. Please clean and build your project. Undeploy it from Tomcat or GlassFish (or the web app server you're using), then redeploy your application. By the way, it looks like you're just not accessing the right way to your page, maybe your URL doesn't fall in the Faces Servlet URL mapping.

Comment: I'm using eclipse Jee Juno . It doesn't work also .Here is my web.xml